# AWS MWS Error: seller is not registered for basic fulfillment

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-mws, fulfillment

When I try to create a fulfillment order via the MWS API, I get the following error:

```
seller is not registered for basic fulfillment
```

My tax information is setup properly in amazon. Is there anything else that could cause this issue?

Thanks,

Comment: Did you search in Google with the error `seller is not registered for basic fulfillment`, before ask question in SO directly? There are a lot of answers already.

Comment: Of course.  There are no answers yet to this question on any forums, only unconfirmed suggestions.